# Erro na função JOIN do MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Minha função JOIN está funcionando porém eu apelido as tabelas e mesmo assim, devido os campos serem idênticos meus inputs que possuem o campo de mesmo nome são preenchidos mesmo se não tiver registro relativo ao id da pessoa na tabela.

```
$result = "SELECT A.id, A.nome, A.inativo, B.tipo_endereco, B.cep, B.tipo_logr, B.nome_logr, B.nume_logr, B.comp_logr, B.cidade, B.bairro, B.uf,"                         
            . " C.operadora, C.telefone, C.email, C.homepage, C.skype, D.cnpj, D.im, D.ie, D.iest, D.cnae, D.razao_social, E.cpf, E.sexo, E.nacionalidade,"             
            . " E.rg, E.orgao_emissor, E.estado_civil, E.data_nascimento AS data_nascimento_pf, F.codigo, F.funcionario, F.data_nascimento AS data_nascimento_func FROM PESSOA A"                                                                                 
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN CADEND B ON (A.ID = B.ID_PESSOA) "                                                                                                       
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN CADCONT C ON (B.ID_PESSOA = C.ID_PESSOA) "                                                                                              
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN PJURIDIC D ON (C.ID_PESSOA = D.ID_PESSOA) "                                                                                             
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN PFISICA E ON (D.ID_PESSOA = E.ID_PESSOA) "
            . " LEFT OUTER JOIN CADFUNC F ON (E.ID_PESSOA = F.ID_PESSOA) WHERE A.id='$id' LIMIT 1";

    $resultado = $conn->query($result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['nome'] = $row['nome'];
        $valores['inativo'] = $row['inativo'];
        $valores['id'] = $row['id'];
        $valores['tipo_endereco'] = $row['tipo_endereco'];
        $valores['cep'] = $row['cep'];
        $valores['tipo_logr'] = $row['tipo_logr'];
        $valores['nome_logr'] = $row['nome_logr'];
        $valores['nume_logr'] = $row['nume_logr'];
        $valores['comp_logr'] = $row['comp_logr'];
        $valores['cidade'] = $row['cidade'];
        $valores['bairro'] = $row['bairro'];
        $valores['uf'] = $row['uf'];
        $valores['operadora'] = $row['operadora'];
        $valores['telefone'] = $row['telefone'];
        $valores['email'] = $row['email'];
        $valores['homepage'] = $row['homepage'];
        $valores['skype'] = $row['skype'];
        $valores['cnpj'] = $row['cnpj'];
        $valores['im'] = $row['im'];
        $valores['ie'] = $row['ie'];
        $valores['iest'] = $row['iest'];
        $valores['cnae'] = $row['cnae'];
        $valores['razao_social'] = $row['razao_social'];
        $valores['cpf'] = $row['cpf'];
        $valores['sexo'] = $row['sexo'];
        $valores['nacionalidade'] = $row['nacionalidade'];
        $valores['rg'] = $row['rg'];
        $valores['orgao_emissor'] = $row['orgao_emissor'];
        $valores['estado_civil'] = $row['estado_civil'];
        $valores['data_nascimento_pf'] = $row['data_nascimento_pf'];
        $valores['codigo'] = $row['codigo'];
        $valores['funcionario'] = $row['funcionario'];
        $valores['data_nascimento_func'] = $row['data_nascimento_func'];
    }
```

neste caso deixei o F.data_nascimento para exemplificar, eu dou JOIN porém não há registro de funcionário nesta tabela CADFUNC então o retorno que tenho são os campos do formulário em branco mas, a data vem preenchida com o valor do input da tabela de pessoa fisica PFISICA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de você usar um apelido (*alias*) para a tabela (na query), isso somente é reconhecido pelo banco de dados.

Você precisa adicionar um alias para a coluna também, pois, o *fetch* que o driver faz desconsidera o nome das tabelas e apenas se preocupa com o nome da coluna.

```
SELECT
    E.data_nascimento as data_nascimento_pf
    F.data_nascimento as data_nascimento_func
    /** restante do sql **/
```

E, posteriormente no PHP, basta recuperar através do *alias*:

```
echo $row['data_nascimento_pf'];
echo $row['data_nascimento_func'];
```

**Update**

Seu problema está justamente aqui:

```
$valores['data_nascimento'] = $row['data_nascimento_pf'];
$valores['data_nascimento'] = $row['data_nascimento_func'];
```

Está atribuindo dois valores distintos na mesma posição (*index*) do *array*.

Além do mais, pra que está passando de uma variável (`$row`) para a outra (`$valores`)?

Use diretamente a variável que você quiser:

```
$valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
```

Comment: obrigado funcionou, então eu coloco $valores para receber $row, pois antes de iniciar meu while eu indico que $valores é um array